# Recursive call blocked

Tags: python, recursion

```
def getCategoriesAsList(element):
    try:
        print "I am {0}".format(element.getNodeID())
        if element.hasChilds():
            for value in element.getChildren().values():
                print "{0} added to list".format(value.getNodeID())
                return [value]+getCategoriesAsList(value)
        else:
            print "{0} added to list".format(element.getNodeID())
            return [element]
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

Good morning!
I am trying to iterate over my tree in python and i want to transform the tree into a list of element with some transformations.
The problem is the function does not perform a recursive call when the element has not child. I make some debug information but i can not understand this behavior!

Comment: `if element.hasChilds():` condition will jump to `else` and return the element in case of no child. Isn't?

Comment: Please give an example of input and current and expected output.

Comment: My Tree has 7 levels only one element in every level was added to the list and it does not perform the other nodes. 

My expection is once "element" node has children, iterate over them and add the child to the list and get down to the next level to check the children of this child until he is a leaf. if it is add him to the list and get up to the upper level to check the next child item in the loop

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi: yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version that preserves the function notation:

```
def getCategoriesAsList(element):
    try:
        print "I am {0}".format(element.getNodeID())
        result = []
        if element.hasChilds():
            for value in element.getChildren().values():
                print "{0} added to list".format(value.getNodeID())
                result.append(value)
                result.extend(getCategoriesAsList(value))
        else:
            print "{0} added to list".format(element.getNodeID())
            result.append(element)
        return result
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

Another option is to use `yield`. It gives you the following solution:

```
def getCategoriesAsList(element):
    try:
        print "I am {0}".format(element.getNodeID())
        if element.hasChilds():
            for value in element.getChildren().values():
                print "{0} added to list".format(value.getNodeID())
                yield value
                for v in getCategoriesAsList(value):
                    yield v
        else:
            print "{0} added to list".format(element.getNodeID())
            yield element
    except Exception as err:
        print err
```

Than just call the function in the following way:

```
print list(getCategoriesAsList(root))
```

Comment: Thanks I made this solution but I want use recursive call without passing params to function
And I am aware that the head is not included into the list

Answer (score 0):

When you return in the `for` loop it won't continue in it. Consider using `yield` keyword instead of `return`.

```
for value in element.getChildren().values():
    print "{0} added to list".format(value.getNodeID
    yield [value]+getCategoriesAsList(value)
```

---

**Explanation:**

When it returns from the for loop, it stops that call to the function and returns whatever variable `value` is.

The `yield` keyword does exactly the same, but continues execution in the current function call, so it will go through all the for loop.

Comment: yield solves the problem of iteration but makes another. I got this error when I run the code : can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list
I add the keyword list when i call the function but it create a list of list and I want all items in one list.

def getCategoriesAsList(element):
        if element.hasChilds():
            for value in element.getChildren().values():
                print "{0} added to list".format(value.getNodeID())
                yield [value]+list(getCategoriesAsList(value))
        else:          
            yield [element]

Comment: If `yield` solves the original question mark it as solved. For the new problem, use `return` in the `else` statement, not `yield`. See if that helps.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and can not add return into a generator

Comment: I meant instead of `else: yield [element]` do `else: return [element]`. 

If doesn't work try in the for loop: `yield getCategoriesAsList(value).append(value)`.

Comment: I apperciate your help but neither of the two solution work for me
I can not use return [element] in a generator
And yield getCategoriesAsList(value).append(value) return an empty list

Comment: What do you mean by _i can't use `return [element] in a generator`_? You are returning a list from a function, you should be able to return it.

Comment: python versions<3.3 do not allow 'return' with argument inside generator

Comment: I don't get it. In your original post you used `return [element]` without errors. Can you post an image with your output error?

Comment: when i make yield in this line  yield [value]+list(getCategoriesAsList(value)) the function become a generator and i can not combine yield with return if i want return value in python version <3.3

Comment: Think i got a better solution. I assume you are using  `xml.etree.ElementTree` module, aren't you? If that's true, I'll post a new answer with a better solution for your original problem.

Comment: I use xml.etree.ElementTree to make a tree of Node element. I make a dictionary to save the tree.
post your solution anyway maybe i change the whole solution if it is better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a final list with all xml `Element` objects, you can use a different approach:

```
def getCategoriesAsList(element):
    i = element.iter()
    return [next(i) for _ in i]
```